# Won't know what type of database will be in use until after I demo a prototype. Is it possible to make that work?

Tags: java, database, netbeans

A relative of mine wants me to to make a program to organize some information at where she works. It's fairly simple, however I don't know what kind of office drama they have going on, but she doesn't want to bother IT with all sorts of questions about the database that can be used, how it will connect (multiple people will read info stored in a database of some sort hosted within the companies intranet).

Anyways, I'm thinking it shouldn't be a problem to just use something like a local Microsoft access database file for now, and then rewrite the database component when I have more information. Is that an insane idea? This program is not hard, it can probably be written and tested in a week if I was working on it full time (I'm still in college). For that matter, I am thinking of using Java in Netbeans simply because I am comfortable with it. Should I worry that I find out they use some sort of database or other solution that cannot be (easily) worked with in Java?

Comment: Your question is way to opinion-based for Stack Overflow.  I would, however, encourage you to look at alternative databases, such as SQL Server Express, Postgres, and MySQL -- all of which are free.

Comment: or even `java db`

Comment: I can't pick the database. I have to use whatever the company uses. My question is whether or not it is reasonable to use whatever for now, demo to the company, and then only have to rework the database component of the program to comply with the company, if they decide they like the demo.

Comment: If you are using JPA or JDBC you should not have to re-work the DB - unless you use DB specific code

Comment: Interesting topic, but much too broad for Stack Overflow. Read about [original intent for Stack Overflow](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/04/16.html) and [launch](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/09/15.html). “…extremely narrow, specific programming question. How do I enlarge a fizzbar without overwriting the user’s snibbit?” By the way, a tip: [H2](http://h2database.com)

Answer (score 1):

While knowing a requirement like database type upfront is a good idea, being able to adapt to new requirements is a part of Agile development.

I'd argue it's not an *insane* idea. If you're careful about your design, switching out database won't be too bad. If you don't mind, I'll elaborate on a (possible) pattern that might save you trouble.

---

## Overview

In my experience I have found it best to abstract the **database logic** (how to communicate) from the **business logic** (how to accomplish a task). These two layers are going to make your code much more maintainable for when you find out the company is running an Oracle database and not Access.

## Data Access Layer

The [DAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) has one job and that is to communicate to the database. It needs to read, it needs to write, and that is it. Your classes will likely include information like table attribute names or queries. It's OK to do that here since the class is specific to a particular database. Using a DAL will greatly simply your database calls later on.

I would **highly suggest** looking into [factory pattern](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) for how to design these classes. Using factory pattern will completely decouple the Business Layer from the database specific classes using interfaces. In other words, you can completely change out the database without needing to modify the business logic.

## Business Layer

In fancy terms, all I'm talking about is the logic for how to accomplish a task. The business layer doesn't have anything to do with where buttons appear on a screen nor should it worry about table names.

In this layer you will find yourself needing access to the database to read/write information and that is when you call on your Data Access Layer. It will handle the ugly details keeping your business logic from having to know what type of database your are using.

## Data Transfer Object

Lastly, you're going to be pushing a lot of information between these layers. I suggest you design some classes that can help you transfer data that belongs together. Consider a call to the DAL requesting a book...

```
Book book = libraryAccessObject.getBookById("ABC123.45");
```

Getting a book is going to return a lot of information. Creating a book object to organize that information will make life easier.

---

In summary, it's not a far fetched idea but be careful with your design. Poor deign now could cause you a lot of problems next week. Layering your code will make it much more maintainable.